# Can't upload files to github - HTTP ERROR 400, crbug/1173575

Tags: github

I'm trying to upload some images to my github repo. In Firefox and Firefox developer edition, I'm getting a blank screen after I click "Commit changes", with an error in the console:

`The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

In Chrome and in Edge, I get a mostly blank page with:
`This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 400`

And in the console:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`
`VM9:7146 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.`

I can't find any information about what might be causing this and it doesn't seem to be happening to anyone else - it was working fine this morning, but is now failing in all browsers.

Edit: This is happening in both my Github accounts, so is not account specific.

Comment: Are you trying to upload these in the issue or pull request message box, or are you trying to add these to the repository itself as part of the contents?  If the latter, you may want to clone the repository and work on it that way.

Comment: Thank you! I was uploading them directly to the repository on the github site. Although direct uploading still isn't working, I did what you suggested, cloned the repository and uploaded via git instead and that is working fine.